# Will the Bamboo Pad (NOT TABLET) work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, hardware, wacom, bamboo

Will the Wacom [Bamboo Pad](http://uk.shop.wacom.eu/products/bamboo/bamboo-pad) work on my Ubuntu mac?

Comment: For the `usb` or `wireless` version of the pad? Have you contacted their support center: https://uk.shop.wacom.eu/contact_en?forceMail=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [FAQ pages of the Linux wacom project](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=FAQ#Which_devices_are_supported.3F) you can find a list of the supported devices.

Answer (score 1):

It must work. You see that Ubuntu supports it (System Settings > Wacom tablet), but pad-s must also work.

Answer (score 1):

I've just bought the Wacom Bamboo Pad and it did not work. Hower, following this instructions (https://bugs.launchpad.net/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1265714/comments/38) worked for me:

Got it perfectly running, now someone can help to get it fixed for all by default. So the steps are:

1. Add `usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0319:0x40000000` to the grub boot
   cmdline(`/etc/default/grub`). Now the tablet is already working with
   wacom driver but automatically assigned wacom driver doesn't support
   touchpad and it's keyboard part
2. I have added to `50-wacom.conf` (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`) the line

   ```
   MatchIsTablet "on"
   ```

in the first section after
 MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|Hanwang|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
This way "evdev" works for keyboard and pad parts of the device and "wacom" only for tablet

Everything works, including three-finger swipes(which are sent by keyboard driver as Alt-Left, Alt-Right, Super etc) and pressure sensitivity of pen!
There must be a better way to match Bamboo Pad without breaking the generic wacom file but I have no experience of doing that, still I will try later if no one else does it faster.
For the wired edition replace 0x0319 with 0x0318 in the grub cmdline
Hooray :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for Ubuntu 15.04, more working details here :

[How to get Bamboo Pad working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)

For step 1, identify your USB device by lsusb :

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 056a:0318 Wacom Co., Ltd
...
```

- wireless Bamdo pad : usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0319:0x40000000
- wired USB Bambo Pad : usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0318:0x40000000

Then add it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub as mentioned above

Comment: If there already is an answer in another question that fits this answer, it is better to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Pabi: please remember that you should only flag as duplicate if the **question** is the same, or very similar, not if the answer is the same. However, in this case the question is clearly the same so I'll flag this question as dupe

Comment: Just a typo, the second `answer` should be `question`.