# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my Wacom tablet CTL-471

Tags: wacom

New Linux user here...

I recently purchased a Wacom Tablet (CTL-471) that I'm planning to use for digital painting and designing on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit OS. I've been using Wacom products on my Windows and Mac machines where I get to use my Wacom pen according to my user preferences. I've seen that Ubuntu has listed a Wacom tablet option under settings, but even after I connected the tablet, the system doesn't recognize it.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPFry.png)

When I use the tablet, though it seems to work well. Even the pressure option works, but in the default configuration. It would be a great help if someone can help me solve this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please look at http://askubuntu.com/a/455855/16395, http://askubuntu.com/a/543559/16395 and http://askubuntu.com/a/713059/16395 --- they're about different tablets models but they apply to your problem.